# Errata list for Humphreys BGG category book

Tags: reference-request, lie-groups, lie-algebras

It seems after the sad passing away of Prof. Humphreys last year his webpage is officially inaccessible. In particular I could not find the errata list to 'Representations of Semisimple Lie Algebras in the BGG Category $\mathscr {O}$.' Does anyone by any chance have a copy of the errata saved that I can get?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can find a copy of the old webpage via the Wayback Machine:

[https://web.archive.org/web/20210128203913/https://people.math.umass.edu/~jeh/](https://web.archive.org/web/20210128203913/https://people.math.umass.edu/%7Ejeh/)

[https://web.archive.org/web/20201014112756/https://people.math.umass.edu/~jeh/pub/book.html](https://web.archive.org/web/20201014112756/https://people.math.umass.edu/%7Ejeh/pub/book.html)

[https://web.archive.org/web/20201014112756/https://people.math.umass.edu/~jeh/pub/bgg.pdf](https://web.archive.org/web/20201014112756/https://people.math.umass.edu/%7Ejeh/pub/bgg.pdf)